# How to trigger the javascript function from the native methods on receiving data from client??

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using the Client - Server side programming and I want to create a chat application in android.So When the data receive from the Client it should automatically call the javascript function.I am using Phonegap for Creating fronend. 
server is receiving data from by using the following code

```
socket.receive(packet);
```

The above code will receive the data from the Client , after receiving it should immediately call the javascript function in the phone gap

Any type of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke  socket.receive(packet) from Phonegap + Android activity file.

After that , invoke js function as below :

```
appView.loadUrl("javascript:yourJSMethod()");
```

Comment: but if the data doesnt receive then the function should not be triggered

Comment: Try to keep above line in if else condition . If you have data then call your JS else do nothing